# scapy : how to manually encode rdata

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

In scapy,

```
rdata     = '\x00\n\x0cmxb-000c6b02\x04gslb\x08pphosted\x03com\x00'
```

really means:

```
10 mxb-000c6b02.gslb.pphosted.com.
```

How can we encode

```
"10 mxb-000c6b02.gslb.pphosted.com."
```

to

```
'\x00\n\x0cmxb-000c6b02\x04gslb\x08pphosted\x03com\x00' using Python3?
```

Thanks!

**Update:**

I hacked up a solution for this after watching the rdata string closely:

```
import struct

def encode_mx_rdata(MXHOST, MX=10):
    _start = struct.pack("!h", int(MX)).decode()

    b = ""
    for i in MXHOST.split("."):
        b += struct.pack("h", len(i) ).decode().rstrip("\x00") + i
    if b and _start:
        return(_start + b + "\x00")
    else: 
        return False
```

In action:

```
In [2]: mxrdata = encode_mx_rdata("mxb-000c6b02.gslb.pphosted.com.", 10)

In [3]: mxrdata 
Out[3]: '\x00\n\x0cmxb-000c6b02\x04gslb\x08pphosted\x03com\x00'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hacked up a solution:

```
import struct

def encode_mx_rdata(MXHOST, MX=10):
    _start = struct.pack("!h", int(MX)).decode()

    b = ""
    for i in MXHOST.split("."):
        b += struct.pack("h", len(i) ).decode().rstrip("\x00") + i
    if b and _start:
        return(_start + b + "\x00")
    else: 
        return False
```

in action:

```
In [2]: mxrdata = encode_mx_rdata("mxb-000c6b02.gslb.pphosted.com.", 10)

In [3]: mxrdata 
Out[3]: '\x00\n\x0cmxb-000c6b02\x04gslb\x08pphosted\x03com\x00'
```

Comment: This be correct with simple DNS packets, but not with more advanced ones. The point of this encoding is to compress the data (by using pointers to portions of DNS addresses that already exist). If you have a packet with the same address used in multiple fields, your trick won’t be like the initial packet

Comment: That’s to say it’s not perfectly doable in current scapy

Comment: @Cukic0d - thanks,  I noticed the same. Question: how can we do compression pointers in python?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at https://github.com/secdev/scapy/pull/1511

It does some basic compression, useable with `DNScompress(packet)`

However if currently does not support partial compression (when you have both a pointer and string in the same rdata/rrname)